# convertir list<> a JSON httppost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Buenas tardes  estoy construyendo una api, que recibe cadena de texto json, el cual utiliza el método post para guardar la información en la base de datos, utilizo un procedimiento almacenado para realizar dicho proceso, estoy utilizando una list<> que es la que me trae la información del json, pero requiero pasara la información a un json para que este pueda ser subido como un parametro al procedimiento almacenado, pero no consigo realizar la conversión y no puedo recorrer el list<> con un foreach porque me dice que no es un elemento inumerable.
La estructura del archivo json es la siguiente:

```
{

    "varios":[{
    "nombre":"David",
    "cantidad":"291123",
     "numero":"205893",
        },
        {
    "nombre":"pedro",
    "cantidad":"295523",
     "numero":"206693",
        },
            {
    "nombre":"maria",
    "cantidad":"295523",
     "numero":"206693",
        }
    ],

}
```

Construí  el list<> según los argumentos del json de esta manera

```
public class cadena
    {
        public List<lista> varios { get; set; }


    }

    public class lista
    {
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public int cantidad { get; set; }
        public int numero { get; set; }
    }
```

Después construí mi controlador  de la siguiente manera donde formato es mi list<> previamente formateado tal como se vio en el codigo anterior

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] cadena formato)
        {
             await _repository.Insert(formato);
            return Ok();


        }
```

Y ahora me traigo la información de list<> a otro método donde debo ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado, donde sugiere que debo pasar mi list<> a un datatable porque este es mas compatible con los objetos de sql o los type del mismo

```
public async Task Insert(cadena formatos)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                                          //
                             DataTable dt = new DataTable();


                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_pruebatype", sql))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tipo", dt));
                    await sql.OpenAsync();
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Construí mi datatable pero no sé cómo pasar el list a mi datatable para luego enviarla como parámetro a mi procedimiento almacenado 
Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: La conversion de tus json a List<T> te la hace bien o te arroja excepcion?

Comment: Me la hace bien, incluso llene el data table manualmente y logre que tomará el data table como parámetro y lo tomo el procedimiento almacenado, la cuestión es que no se como pasar el. List a datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta a mi inconveniente, al principio pensaba que debía enviar la lista<> a un datatable, pero la mejor forma fue crear una variable de tipo json y deserializarla, acontinuacion muestro lo que se hizo para la solución: aclaro que formatos es un parámetro de tipo lista<> que viene del controlador (POST)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public async Task Insert(cadena formatos)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {                           

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formatos);


            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_pruebatype", sql))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@json", json));                  

                await sql.OpenAsync();
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes rellenar tu DataTable de esta forma abreviada. Datatable tiene mas propiedades para poder usar y sea mas poderoso el uso que este ejemplo simple que te estoy dejando, pero que funciona.
Te dejo la documentacion de Microsoft para que revises.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=netcore-3.1#System_Data_DataTable_Load_System_Data_IDataReader_

```
using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
         //Libreria using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
         var v = serializer.Deserialize<cadena>(json);

         DataTable dt = new DataTable();

         dt.Columns.Add("nombre");
         dt.Columns.Add("cantidad");
         dt.Columns.Add("numero");

         foreach (var item in v.varios)
         {
            dt.Rows.Add(item.nombre,item.cantidad, item.numero);

         }

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_pruebatype", sql))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tipo", dt));
                await sql.OpenAsync();
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                return;
            }
        }
```